# Have a Class and a Subclass handled the same way?

Tags: java

I have a class called `Image` and a class that extends it called `ImageSheet`.

`ImageSheet` is the same as `Image` except it has additional fields such as the number of frames on the sheet of images.

What I want to do is have it so I can call `drawImage(img, frame)` and have `img` be either a `Image` or an `ImageSheet` and handle them with the same method with the only difference being that if it's an `Image` then the `frame` field is ignored but when it's an `ImageSheet` the `frame` field is read and used to draw the specific frame.

I'm trying to avoid having separate methods for if it's an `Image` or an `ImageSheet` because I already have 3 different `drawImage()` methods that accept different input variables and if I did one for each class I'd have 3 pairs of methods where each pair is essentially exactly the same.

How can I pull off what I have in mind?

Comment: have an abstract class AbstractImage. add abstract methods to it and can call your image or imagesheet by extending this abstract class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that drawImage is a method outside Image/ImageSheet and if you are avoiding a separate method, you may use instanceof and check if the img parameter is an instance of imageSheet.

Comment: Yes you are correct `drawImage` is a method of the class that handles rendering the game world. `instanceof` sounds like what I want but I wonder are there any drawbacks to using it? Usually something so convienient is costly and causes performance issues. That and is it a sign of poor design if I need it?

Comment: i don't think it would cause a huge performance difference since all you need to do is know the type in order to perform what you need. In my opinion, using instanceof is not a sign of poor design because it is really used in cases where knowing type of the object is a necessity.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have the `Image`/`ImageSheet` classes handle the frame processing themselves?

For example, have the `Image` class have some method named process(frame) that then ignores the frame parameter sent in, and have `ImageSheet` override the process(frame) method with whatever processing you wanted the `ImageSheet`-specific object to do.

Then, you can have:

```
void drawImage(Image img, Frame frame) { img.process(frame); }
```

and it will do the appropriate thing depending on whether it's an `Image` or `ImageSheet`. Hope I'm understanding your question correctly!

Edit:

To clarify, here's the code for your `Image` and `ImageSheet` classes, respectively.

```
class Image {
  ... 
  public void process(Frame frame) { 
    // do something 
  }
}

class ImageSheet extends Image{
  ...
  // override process(Frame frame) method from Image
  public void process(Frame frame) { 
    // do something different 
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax used in your example, what is that doing exactly?

Comment: You tagged this as a Java question, right - isn't this plain Java method declaration/invocation syntax? I'm calling a process method that I've defined on the `Image` class (and overridden on the `ImageSheet` class).

Comment: I was confused by how drawImage doesn't do anything except call `img.process(frame)`, why not just directly call `process()` then?

Comment: The point is having the img object handle the processing itself, because you can override its behavior in the `ImageSheet` class if you want it to do something different.

Answer (score 1):

As ImageSheet extends Image you can the signature on the `drawImage(img, frame)` method should be `drawImage(Image img, Frame frame)`. To differentiate between `Image`and `ImageSheet` objects use the `instanceOf` operator. 
Example:

```
public void drawImage(Image img, Frame frame) {
  if(img instanceof ImageSheet) {
    // handle ImageSheet
  } else {
    // handle all other Image instances
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the `drawImage(...)` methods are external to both `Image` and `ImageSheet`. In this case there are a number of potential solutions:

- (This might be controversial) `Image` is in all effects an `ImageSheet` with a fixed number of frames (1); as such, you do not have to take care about `Image` being different;
- If this solution is unsuitable, you may use a double dispatch, i.e. having the external renderer entity call a method `drawImage(frame)` (and possibly other variants, as I have understood from your words) declared in the `Image` class and as such present in every subclass; this is kind of similar to the `Visitor` pattern.
- Last but not least, do not use an external renderer but have `Image`s render themselves using a method `drawImage(RenderingContext)` where you can put all the possible feature requests of the rendering being performed.

Comment: May be this post is not leading to the solution.

Comment: I don't agree with the last bullet there because I'm trying to keep the game world abstracted from the engine/framework. (I'm making a game) So in the future I could just swap the renderer with something else but leave the game world code alone.